# How to parse same named child elements based on attributes with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <GetGridResult xmlns="http://namespace.net/functions/GetGridResult">
            <GRIDRESULT type="LIST.DATA_ONLY.STORED">
                <DATASPY id="105429" label="VAN" />
                <TOOLBAR jsonclass="object" />
                <GRID>
                    <METADATA>
                        <REQUEST_TYPE_META>LIST.DATA_ONLY.STORED</REQUEST_TYPE_META>
                        <RECORDS>446</RECORDS>
                        <CLIENTROWS>5</CLIENTROWS>
                        <ISSYSTEMUSER>false</ISSYSTEMUSER>
                    </METADATA>
                    <DATA jsonclass="array">
                        <ROW id="1">
                            <D n="5">4451</D><D n="13">BO</D><D n="15">C</D><D n="16">Closed</D><D n="22">0301</D><D n="26">01/26/2015 00:00</D><D n="122">CMBC</D><D n="279">236366</D><D n="608">REP</D><D n="694">BR</D><D n="757">BAD AC</D><D n="1900" />
                            <D n="4998">2</D><D n="6941">A</D>
                        </ROW>
                        <ROW id="2">
                            <D n="5">4451</D><D n="13">BO</D><D n="15">C</D><D n="16">Closed</D><D n="22">0665</D><D n="26">01/23/2015 00:00</D><D n="122">CMBC</D><D n="279">236367</D><D n="608">REP</D><D n="694">BR</D><D n="757">DOOR CONTROL</D><D n="1900" />
                            <D n="4998">2</D><D n="6941">A</D>
                        </ROW>
                    </DATA>
                </GRID>
            </GRIDRESULT>
        </GetGridResult>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to retrieve all the rows (there are more than I'm showing here) and obtain a number of the "D" elements based on the attributes to output the following:

```
<WorkOrderResponse>
    <WorkOrders>
        <WorkOrder>
            <WorkOrderId>236366</WorkOrderId>
            <Description>BAD AC</Description>
            <DateReported>01/26/2015 00:00</DateReported>
            <ClassId>BO</ClassId>
            <ProblemCode>0301</ProblemCode>
            <ActionCode>REP</ActionCode>
        </WorkOrder>
        <WorkOrder>
            <WorkOrderId>236367</WorkOrderId>
            <Description>DOOR CONTROL</Description>
            <DateReported>01/23/2015 00:00</DateReported>
            <ClassId>BO</ClassId>
            <ProblemCode>0665</ProblemCode>
            <ActionCode>REP</ActionCode>
        </WorkOrder>    
    </WorkOrders>
</WorkOrderResponse>
```

Here's the XSL that I've been working with, however, I can't seem to get this working. You will see that I'm trying to pull the D elements based on the attribute "n", i.e. "D[@n='279']".

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ax21="http://samples.esb.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://namespace.net/functions/GetGridResult/GetGridResult" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="ns fn" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <WorkOrdersResponse>
            <WorkOrders>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </WorkOrders>
        </WorkOrdersResponse>       
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DATA"> 
        <xsl:for-each select="ROW">
            <WorkOrder>
                <WorkOrderId>
                    <xsl:value-of select="D[@n='279']"/>
                </WorkOrderId>
                <Description>
                    <xsl:value-of select="D[@n='757']"/>
                </Description>
                <DateReported>
                    <xsl:value-of select="D[@n='26']"/>
                </DateReported>
                <ClassId>
                    <xsl:value-of select="D[@n='13']"/>
                </ClassId>
                <ProblemCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="D[@n='22']"/>
                </ProblemCode>
                <ActionCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="D[@n='608']"/>
                </ActionCode>
            </WorkOrder>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's what is currently being spitting out when I run the xsl against the sample xml. Any ideas? Please help me out here. Thanks in advance!

```
<GetWorkOrdersResponse xmlns:ax21="http://samples.esb.wso2.org/xsd">
  <WorkOrders>
        LIST.DATA_ONLY.STORED 446 5 false

        4451BOCClosed030101/26/2015 00:00CMBC236366REPBRBAD AC 2A

        4451BOCClosed066501/23/2015 00:00CMBC236367REPBRDOOR CONTROL 2A
</WorkOrders>
</GetWorkOrdersResponse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues:

First, you declare this in the `stylesheet` tag:

```
xmlns:ns="http://namespace.net/functions/GetGridResult/GetGridResult"
```

but the actual namespace used in the input XML is:

```
"http://namespace.net/functions/GetGridResult"
```

Next, you are not actually using the prefix you have assigned to the namespace - so your XPath expressions do not match/select anything.

Finally, you are applying templates to nodes you do not want to process. This will cause unwanted text nodes to appear in your output, due to the action of built-in template rules.

Here's your stylesheet, corrected:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:ax21="http://samples.esb.wso2.org/xsd" 
xmlns:ns="http://namespace.net/functions/GetGridResult"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions" 
exclude-result-prefixes="ns fn" 
version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <WorkOrdersResponse>
            <WorkOrders>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//ns:DATA"/>
            </WorkOrders>
        </WorkOrdersResponse>       
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns:DATA"> 
        <xsl:for-each select="ns:ROW">
            <WorkOrder>
                <WorkOrderId>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns:D[@n='279']"/>
                </WorkOrderId>
                <Description>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns:D[@n='757']"/>
                </Description>
                <DateReported>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns:D[@n='26']"/>
                </DateReported>
                <ClassId>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns:D[@n='13']"/>
                </ClassId>
                <ProblemCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns:D[@n='22']"/>
                </ProblemCode>
                <ActionCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns:D[@n='608']"/>
                </ActionCode>
            </WorkOrder>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Of course, you could shorten the whole thing to just:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xpath-default-namespace="http://namespace.net/functions/GetGridResult">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/"> 
    <WorkOrdersResponse>
        <WorkOrders>
            <xsl:for-each select="//ROW">
                <WorkOrder>
                    <WorkOrderId>
                        <xsl:value-of select="D[@n='279']"/>
                    </WorkOrderId>
                    <Description>
                        <xsl:value-of select="D[@n='757']"/>
                    </Description>
                    <DateReported>
                        <xsl:value-of select="D[@n='26']"/>
                    </DateReported>
                    <ClassId>
                        <xsl:value-of select="D[@n='13']"/>
                    </ClassId>
                    <ProblemCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="D[@n='22']"/>
                    </ProblemCode>
                    <ActionCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="nD[@n='608']"/>
                    </ActionCode>
                </WorkOrder>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </WorkOrders>
    </WorkOrdersResponse>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that `xpath-default-namespace` is an XSLT 2.0 feature.

Comment: Thanks Michael, this worked great. I appreciate you taking the time to help me out.